# No heads together?

Tags: probability

A coin has probability $p$ of showing head when tossed. It is tossed $n$ times. Let $P_n$ be the probability that no two or more consecutive heads occur? What is $P_n$ for any $n≥3$.
I proved it individually fo

Comment: [This guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) contains a lot of pointers for how to format mathematical text. Specifically, `$P_n$` gives $P_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u_n$ be the number of sequences of length $n$ composed with T and H such that there are no two consecutive H. We have $u_1=2$ and $u_2=3$.

A sequence of $n+1$ throws can end with a T, there are $u_n$ such sequences, or by a H, which has to be preceded by a T. There are $u_{n-1}$ such sequences.

So $(u_n)$ follow the recurrence :
$$u_1=2,\,u_2=3\text{ and }(\forall n\ge2)\,u_{n+1}=u_n+u_{n-1}$$
So $(u_n)$ is simply a "shifted" Fibonacci sequence.

With your usual method to solve those recurrences, you find :
$$u_n=\frac{5+3\sqrt5}{10}(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2})^n + \frac{5-3\sqrt5}{10}(\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2})^n$$
And the seeked probability is 
$$P_n=\frac{u_n}{2^n}$$